# ¿Por qué Ajax en Django 1.6.5 me da error 500?

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, django

Quisiera saber por qué me lanza un error de servidor (500).

Necesito realizar o importar algún otro tipo de librería o módulo para hacer funcionar mi petición `ajax` ?

```
$("#email").change(function(){
                $.ajax({
                    data : { "email": $(this).val() },
                    url : "/validar-email/",
                    type : "GET",
                    dataType : 'json',
                    contentType: 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
                    success : function(data){
                        console.log(data);
                    }
                });
            });
```

Función en la vista

```
def ValidarEmail(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        data = serializers.serialize('json', {'respuesta':'ok'})
        return HttpResponse(data, content_type='application/json')
```

Answer (score -1):

No se mucho de Django pero el error 500 significa que tienes error en el servidor, el cual esta siendo causado por la función ValidarEmail, leyendo un poco la documentacion el error se debe a que como segundo para metro a la función seralize le estas pasando un string y no un QuerySet, para solucionar esto podrias usar la funcion JsonResponse (disponible a partir de django 1.7) de la siguiente manera:

```
from django.http import JsonResponse
def ValidarEmail(request):
if request.is_ajax():
    data = {'respuesta':'ok'}
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(data), content_type='application/json') //esto deberia funcionarte 
    return JsonResponse({'respuesta':'ok'})//djan1.7+
```

Comment: Lamentablemente no puedo utilizar la funcion JsonResponse, ya que todavia no he podido migrar mi proyecto a Django 1.7. Pero con respecto al parametro que no he pasado (el Queryset) voy a probar con eso. Luego te aviso. Muchas gracias. Saludos